# unable to implement Formatter2 in xtext lsp

Tags: xtext, formatter

configured formatter in mwe2

```
formatter = {
                generateStub = true
                generateXtendStub = true
            }
```

binding it in AbstractTableRuleDslRuntimeModule also

```
public Class<? extends IFormatter2> bindIFormatter2() {
        return TableRuleDslFormatter.class;
    }
```

trying to call formatter method using serializer functionality

```
serializer.serialize(ruleModel,SaveOptions.newBuilder().format().getOptions());
```

after all config and implementation serializer is using onewhitespaceformatter instead of xtext formatter
[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H7uj.png)

How can i switch default formatter to my xtext formatter

Comment: can you explain what you exactly want to do? Xtext LSP has formatter service already implemented. also it is normal that both are there, formatter 1 and formatter 2 provider. the serialialize method should then prefer formatter 2 over formatter 1

Comment: yep but it's using formatter 1 over formatter 2 idk why

Comment: Can you debug the code? EG with a unit test

Comment: We are trying to implement a standalone serializer to format the xtext (text document) using our xtend formatter.

Comment: did debug to but onewhitespace is getting set by default

Comment: Can you please provide a complete reproducing project with unit test

Comment: And this is not about getting set, it is about the code that uses it. It checks for formatter2 first, formatter1 second

Comment: I also cannot reproduce in a simple example